# Panda Grapher without sorting data - 2

Tags: python, pandas, pandasgui, grapher

I am a new user of PandasGUI. I just read the data table and want to see a quick line chart:

MWE:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandasgui import show

my_data = pd.read_csv('test.txt',sep='\t')
print(my_data)

show(my_data)
```

test.txt:

```
x   y
0   0
6   1
7   8
9   9
3   8
2   1
0   0
```

The point is that my data is hysteresis (different yvalues as x increases and decreases ), as here (the numbers represent the index of points):

[image]

I can not see this hysteresis because Grapher sorts the data by x before plotting, as here:

[image]

Is it possible to disable sorting? I see that there is a Custom Kwargs, but I can not find the list of Kwargs anywhere.

(Disclaimer: This is the repost of the previously closed question, now much improved, because the reopening was denied.)